# Bootstrap Table refresh

Tags: javascript, ajax, bootstrap-table

I am using bootstrap table to display data from my MongoDB, using a mongoid query. I would like to refresh the table at an interval of 5 minutes. I've read the documentation, but being new to Javascript, I'm not sure how to accomplish this - whether to use an Ajax call or just a setTimeout() function, etc.

This is my table code:

```
<table id="table" data-show-refresh="true" data-row-style="rowStyle" data-toggle="table" data-url="http://maccdx160121:4567/api/v1/currentsat*">
    <thead>
        <tr>

           <th data-field="initials">Initials</th>
            <th data-cell-style="cellStyle" data-field="sector">Sector</th>
            <th data-field="cjs">CJS</th>


        </tr>
    </thead>
 </table>
```

This is my Mongoid query, if it helps:

```
get '/currentsat*' do

    #SatTransaction.where( current: true, :initials.ne => nil, :position.in => ["RDR", "SPVR", "OJI"] ).to_json
    SatTransaction.where( current: true, :shift_duration.ne => 0, ).and(SatTransaction.or({:position.in => ["SPVR", "RDR", "OJI"]},{sector: "BREAK"}).selector).to_json


    end



end

before do
  cache_control :no_cache
end

def with_captured_stdout
  old_stdout = $stdout
  $stdout = StringIO.new('', 'w')
  yield
  $stdout.string
ensure
  $stdout = old_stdout
end
```

Thanks for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you remove the table and recreate that:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $('#table').remove();
    $('#Table_Parent').append(Table_Html);
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do the both. You need to get the data from the server using ajax and then reload it into the datatable.

Only refreshing the data table will just reload the data what you have in your html but you need to refresh because it will reload the chaged data.

as @Farzin Kanzi code, inside the set time out make the ajax call and reload with server data

```
setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax(
    ...
    success(response) {
      Table_Html = resopnse
    }
   )
    $('#table').remove();
    $('#Table_Parent').append(Table_Html);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: I think I see what you are doing, but I am unsure how to incorporate it into my code. I was able to piece together the following javascript that works for what I need, albeit not as professional as an ajax call.
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () { 
      location.reload();
    }, 60 * 1000);
</script>